# Validation error selectOneListbox. Entity @OneToOne relationship

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I tried to make same list as in the below link:
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/listbox.xhtml

Unfortunately I get validation error:

```
Select Box: Validation Error: Value is not valid
```

I don't know where I've made mistake. I read a lot about this issue (in most cases it was solved by BalusC) however still can't find the issue.

If you can help I really appreciate.

`StoreHouse.java`

```
@Entity
public class StoreHouse implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;

@OneToOne
private Supply supply;

@Column(nullable = false)
private Integer amount;
//geters setters namedqueryies
```

`Supply.java`

```
@Entity
public class Supply implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;

@Column(unique = true, nullable = false, length = 32)
private String name;

@Column(length = 1024)
private String description;

@Column
private Double price;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@NotNull
private SupplyType supplyType;
//geters setters namedqueryies
```

`StoreHouseController.java`

```
@ManagedBean
public class StoreHouseController implements Serializable {

@Inject
private StoreHouseBean storeHouseBean; // DAO for storeHouse 

@ManagedProperty("#{supplyController}")
private SupplyController supplyController; //Manged bean for Supply 

private StoreHouse storeHouse = new StoreHouse();
private List<Supply> allSupplies;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    allSupplies = supplyController.findAll();
}

public void check() {
    System.out.println("storeHousetheme" + storeHouse.toString()); // Function just to check if the supply was set
}
```

`SupplyConverter.java`

```
@FacesConverter("supplyConverter")
public class SupplyConverter implements Converter {

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {

    if (value != null && value.trim().length() > 0) {

        try {
            SupplyController supplyController = (SupplyController) context.getExternalContext().getApplicationMap().get("supplyController");
            Supply supply = supplyController.findById(Integer.parseInt(value));
            System.out.println("CONVERTER:" + supply.toString());
            return supply;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Conversion error", "ERROR."));
        }
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object object) {
    if (object != null) {
        return String.valueOf(((Supply) object).getId());
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

`view.xhtml`

```
<h:form>
<p:messages autoUpdate="true" />
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
    <h:outputLabel value="Nazwa" />
    <p:selectOneListbox id="supplies" value="#{storeHouseController.storeHouse.supply}" converter="supplyConverter" var="s" filter="true" label="Select Box">
        <f:selectItems value="#{storeHouseController.allSupplies}" var="supply" itemLabel="#{supply.name}" itemValue="#{supply}"/>
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{s.name}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:selectOneListbox>
    <p:commandButton action="#{storeHouseController.check}" type="submit" value="submit" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

If you need any other file/class please just add comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few more days of searching and googling I've found the solution. I'm a bit angry that this is not posted anywhere on primefaces because I've lost many hours to fix the issue.

It came out that I did not overwrite `equals` method of `Supply` class which is required.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final Supply other = (Supply) obj;
    if (!Objects.equals(this.id, other.id)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!Objects.equals(this.name, other.name)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (this.supplyType != other.supplyType) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I believe that this topic will help someone in the future...

Answer (score 0):

Your SelectItem-value is your object, so the toString()-method is called and you get something like "Supply@44de6bae".
Then, your controller tries to parse it to int and fails. Try...

```
<f:selectItems value="#{...}" var="..." itemLabel="..." itemValue="#{supply.id}"/>
```

If the error occures while loading the page, this might help as well as at least some components don't like "none-basic-type-or-enum" values. I hope this helped, Greez.

Comment: `java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to pl.gw.model.Supply`

Comment: when? occured in which class?

Comment: After changing the itemvalue to supply.id. In my opinion we should have there object not integer.

Comment: When you do it your was (with `itemValue="#{supply}"`), what does the converter get as value and by calling `Integer.parseInt(value)`?

Comment: It get's `String` which represents id of the supply object.